# C++ timing method with lower sys time

Tags: c++, timing

I'm trying to make my program self timed and I know two methods

1) using getrusage

```
truct rusage startu; struct rusage endu;
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &startu); 

//Do computation here

getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &endu);
double start_sec = start.ru_utime.tv_sec + startu.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000000.0; 
double end_sec = endu.ru_utime.tv_sec + endu.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000000.0; 
double duration = end_sec - start_sec;
```

This fetches the user time of a program segment.

2) using clock(), which gets the processor's executing time

```
double start_sec = (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

//Do computation here

double end_sec = (double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double duration = end_sec - start_sec;
```

This fetches the real time of a program segment.

However, I get really long sys time for both methods. The user time is also longer than without these timings. System time sometimes even doubles the user time.

For example, I'm doing Traveling Salesman Problem, for a input that runs around 3 seconds for both user and real time normally, these two timings both make the user time to be over 5 seconds and real time over 15 secs, which means sys time is around 10 seconds long.

I hope to know if there are ways of improvements or other libraries that are capable of shortening the sys time and user time if possible. If I have to user other libraries, I want libraries for both user time timing and real time timing.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you calling your profiling code inside a tight loop?

Comment: @MarkB Yes I do I have a backtracking recursion which is called consecutively, in which iterations through a vector is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to carefully read the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page and to consider also the [clock_gettime(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) syscall.

Comment: "System CPU time is the time spent by the kernel executing in system mode on behalf of the process". I think this means as long as I call system timing functions, system time will have to take this long?

Comment: @ljhljh235: No, it's all system calls, not only timing functions. Typically high system fraction means a process doing lots of I/O.

Comment: @janneb Thanks! I also noticed this when I print a lot of debug infos. But for this time, I don't have a lot of I/O - simple file input and only 2 lines standard output.